# How to call an Excel custom ribbon button from the immediate window?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

Having a procedure `c1()`, that looks like this:

```
Sub c1(control As IRibbonControl)
    Debug.Print "foo"
End Sub
```

it is being called successfully from the ribbon, with the correct code `onAction="c1"/>`

**Question:**
How to call the same procedure from the immediate window (for debugging purposes)? It is asking for a parameter, which I do not know how to provide:

[image]

Comment: why don't you put a `stop` or breakpoint in the sub code and click the button?

Comment: what do you use `control ` parameter for?

Comment: you could use `Sub c1(Optional control As IRibbonControl)`

Comment: @user3598756  `control` is the reference to the ribbon control clicked to run this sub. The code cannot be changed as you like.

Comment: @user3598756 - the control parameter is the standard way to create a ribbon control.

Comment: You could mimic a mouse click on a (custom) Ribbon button with the help of the API function AccessibleChildren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code in `c1` does not rely on the `control` you can use

```
c1 nothing
```

in the immediate window.

---

What you can do for example:

```
Private lobjRibbon As IRibbonUI

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef source As Any, ByVal length As Long)

Public Sub Ribbon_CallbackOnLoad(ByRef probjRibbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set lobjRibbon = probjRibbon
    Range("A1").Value = CStr(ObjPtr(lobjRibbon)) 'write the pointer to a cell to save it even if VBA stops
End Sub
```

with `Ribbon_CallbackOnLoad` you set the ribbon on load to the variable `lobjRibbon` or save it's pointer (in case VBA completely ends).

You can use

```
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
    Dim objRibbon As Object
    Call CopyMemory(objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer))
    Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
    Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function
```

to get the ribbob object back from its saved pointer for example like in

```
Sub RefreshRibbon(Optional ControlID As String = vbNullString)
    If lobjRibbon Is Nothing Then
        Set lobjRibbon = GetRibbon(CLngPtr(Range("A1").Value))

        If ControlID = vbNullString Then
            lobjRibbon.Invalidate
        Else
            lobjRibbon.InvalidateControl ControlID
        End If
    Else
        If ControlID = vbNullString Then
            lobjRibbon.Invalidate
        Else
            lobjRibbon.InvalidateControl ControlID
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I was looking for! :)

Comment: As an additional question - is there still a way to declare the ribbon?

Comment: @Vityata X/Y-problem? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Just calling the ribbon button from the immediate window / (or from code) would be ok. But if there was a nice way to refer the ribbon from the code, it would open plenty of new opportunities :)

Comment: could you show the code snippet that builds/refers to the new control and its parents?

Comment: @Vityata have a look, I'm not sure if that meets what you were looking for.

Comment: partially - getting the ribbon onload and saving it anywhere is a no-go. I hoped there would be a quick & fancy way to say `ThisRibbon.Tabs.Icon(n)`, from whichever part of the code I wanted.

Comment: @Vityata well have a look here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm maybe you can find what you are looking for there. But I think that is the only way to get access to the ribbon object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround

```vb
Sub c1(control As IRibbonControl)
    call c1_subroutine
End Sub

Sub c1_subroutine()
    Debug.Print "foo"
End Sub
```

And in the immediate window call `c1_subroutine`

Comment: what if the code depends on `control`? `c1_subroutine` would not work then.

Comment: This will work, but my idea is to find a way to declare the ribbon from the immediate window.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I saw `Debug.Print "foo"` and assumed the code doesn't need the `IRibbonControl`. @Viyata, sorry I misunderstood the question, but @Pᴇʜ provided a great answer.